# Building classes from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, class, dictionary, inheritance

So I am new to all this, please pardon my poor formatting and only loose grasp of jargon.

In short, I have a

```
coins = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getcurrencies")
```

that returns json() nested dictionaries (sorry for terrible phrasing) that look like this:

```
{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : [{
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "CurrencyLong" : "Bitcoin",
        "MinConfirmation" : 2,
        "TxFee" : 0.00020000,
        "IsActive" : true,
        "CoinType" : "BITCOIN",
        "BaseAddress" : null
    }, {
        "Currency" : "LTC",
        "CurrencyLong" : "Litecoin",
        "MinConfirmation" : 5,
        "TxFee" : 0.00200000,
        "IsActive" : true,
        "CoinType" : "BITCOIN",
        "BaseAddress" : null
    }]
}
```

In short I would like to access each dictionary within `coins["result"]` and build my own values with them to generate a class for each coin so that the inherited code gets filled, like:

```
class coinbuilder(self, currency, currencyLong, minConfirmation...):
    def __init__(self):
        self.currency = currency
        self.currencyLong = currencyLong
    ticker = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-" + currency)
```

I understand this code is incorrect, but Im trying to give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. Sorry for my terrible phrasing, im new to programming in general and while I have a general grasp of function I am still trying to catch up on jargon.

Comment: Good advice from Ned:
 [keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).  You are already in the good situation and are trying to go into the bad situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a total script for what you are trying to do:

```
import requests
import json

class CoinBuilder:
  def __init__(self,dict):
    self.currency = dict['Currency']
    self.currencyLong = dict['CurrencyLong']
    self.minConfirmation = dict['MinConfirmation']
    self.txFee = dict['TxFee']
    self.isActive = dict['IsActive']
    self.coinType = dict['CoinType']
    self.baseAddress = dict['BaseAddress']
    self.notice = dict['Notice']


coins_response = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getcurrencies")

all_coins = json.loads(coins_response.content)

list_of_coin_obs = []

for coin in all_coins["result"]:
  list_of_coin_obs.append(CoinBuilder(coin))
```

This script is getting the response, then iterating through the dictionaries in `result[]` and building `CoinBuilder` objects from that. All of the created objects are also being stored in a list, `list_of_coin_obs[]`.

You can then print the first 10 results you have, for example, like  this:

```
# Print out the first 10 coins
print("First 10 coins:")
for i in range(1,11):
  print(i,") ",list_of_coin_obs[i].currency)
```

For this example, this would output:

```
First 10 coins:
1 )  LTC
2 )  DOGE
3 )  VTC
4 )  PPC
5 )  FTC
6 )  RDD
7 )  NXT
8 )  DASH
9 )  POT
10 )  BLK
```

If you wanted to create a method to look up a specific coin by it's ticker symbol, you could create something like this:

```
# method to retrieve a specific coin from 'list_of_coin_obs[]'
#   we are passing in a parameter, 'coin_abr' to give to our filter
def get_specific_coin_by_abr(coin_abr):
  return next(filter(lambda x: x.currency == coin_abr, list_of_coin_obs)) 
# call our method, which returns a 'CoinBuilder' type  
specific_coin = get_specific_coin_by_abr('BTC')
# print our results to show it worked
print('CurrencyName: ',specific_coin.currency,'CurrencyLong: ',specific_coin.currencyLong)
```

This prints:

```
CurrencyName:  BTC CurrencyLong:  Bitcoin
```

**Note:** This is assuming that you already have the `list_of_coin_obs[]` created and in the same scope as this method.

One suggestion, here the class name `CoinBuilder` doesn't *totally* make the most sense. A better name for the class/objects would simply be `Coin` or `NamedCurrency` or some other similar name. I think I know what you were going for, but this is probably a better fit for your project.

Best of luck.

Comment: This seems to be closer to what I want so far. Though when I attempt to `print(list_of_coin_obs)` its all encoded? 

I understand how to call a grouping with this setup, like for instance printing out `list_of_coin_obs.currency` and getting a list of them, but how do I access each individual dictionary? Like if I wanted to call the ADA / Cardano dictionary for instance

Comment: So, `list_of_coin_obs` is not going to be a list of dictionaries, but rather a list of objects of the `CoinBuilder` class. If you want to access each object in the list, you can iterate through it like any other list, such as `for coin in list_of_coin_obs:` etc

Comment: For your ADA/Cardano example, you can access a specific object in the list a number of ways - one way is the following: `specific_coin = next(filter(lambda x: x.currency == 'ADA',  list_of_coin_obs))` which you could then print with `print('CurrencyName: ',specific_coin.currency,'CurrencyLong: ',specific_coin.currencyLong,)`

Comment: Thank you, Ill chew on this for a while and do a little reading to make sure I know exactly whats happening.

Comment: sure, ask if you need more explanation

Comment: First off thank you for being so helpful. I genuinely want to learn to code efficiently and I feel I learned a fair amount researching the methods you used here.

That said, in my novice attempts I tried to automate the `next(filter(lambda())` process through functions and class only to keep getting `StopIteration` errors. I learned a fair amount about the process of iterators and how return / classes must call a `StopIteration` which obviously doesnt do well with `next()`.

Comment: So I thought maybe I could make a list of the coin names as variables  like this:

    `coin_collection = [BTC, ADA, XLM, ETH]` 
and run a `for` loop but I believe that also runs into the same `StopIteration` problem.

So my question I suppose is how would I structure a class or function to run that `next(filter())` loop on given variables? 

Currently typing out...

    `ADA = next(filter(lambda x: x.currency == 'ADA', list_of_coin_obs))
BTC = next(filter(lambda x: x.currency == 'BTC', list_of_coin_obs))
ETH = next(filter(lambda x: x.currency == 'ETH', list_of_coin_obs))`

Comment: @Deadmon I've updated the answer with what I think you're going for, lmk if it works for you

Comment: Not quite, now I am running into 
`BTC = next(filter(lambda x: x.currency == 'BTC', list_of_coin_obs)) TypeError: filter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Im not sure why I am running into this error when the same setup was working fine previously.

Comment: Also thank you for all your help, pending you reply to the error above Ill be digging through google and other Stackoverflows for other aspects of this project. Youve helped plenty and dont wanna be a bother haha

Comment: Yeah sorry, don't know why that error would start happening now, code runs fine on my end :/ . As far as asking for help, it's no problem! We are all here to help when you get stuck, just so long as you are willing to share what you have tried first. We were all new to programming at one point (even though some people here will pretend they weren't). Just be open to learning and growing and you will be fine :). Best of luck in your project, sounds fun

Answer (score 3):

There are several different ways to do this, you could parse the dictionary inside your `__init__` function for example.

I tend to handle this by having a separate `@classmethod` that is responsible for parsing dictionaries to create instances of my class.

Something like this:

```
class Coinbuilder:
    def __init__(self, cur, curlong):
      self.currency = cur
      self.currency_long = curlong

    @classmethod
    def build_from_dict(coin_b, d):
      attributes = {'Currency', 'CurrencyLong'}
      try:
        class_dct = {a: d[a] for a in attributes}
      except:
        raise ValueError('Input did not contain necessary attributes')
      return coin_b(class_dct['Currency'], class_dct['CurrencyLong'])
```

This way I am not forced to pass `Coinbuilder` a dictionary to create a class instance, but I have a simple method I can use to parse a dictionary to create an instance of my class.

For this simple example, I can do the following:

```
x = Coinbuilder.build_from_dict({'Currency': 'BTC', 'CurrencyLong': 'Bitcoin'})
```

Or I could use:

```
y = Coinbuilder('BTC', 'Bitcoin')
```

And get two equal class instances:

```
print(x.currency, x.currency_long)
print(y.currency, y.currency_long)
```

Output:

```
BTC Bitcoin
BTC Bitcoin
```

Using your sample input as a guide, once you write your `@classmethod` to parse your dictionary, you could then simply use:

```
my_coins = []
for result in coins['result']:
    my_coins.append(Coinbuilder.build_from_dict(result))
```

Or:

```
my_coins = [Coinbuilder.build_from_dict(result) for result in coins['result']]
```